# constant display of uploaded image React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a page where i display a static image. I want to display there the image i just uploaded. For that I have implemented file upload using express-fileUpload on my server and its working fine, it gets the photo and saves it into a folder, but i cannot display it on my page ( after page refresh it disappears).
How could i make this image remain even after refresh?

server.js code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const Years = require('./models/yearModel')
const Users = require('./models/userModel')
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const cors = require('cors')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(fileUpload())

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    if (req.files === null) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
    }

    const file = req.files.file;
    const fileName = "orar.jpg"+file.name

    file.mv(`${__dirname}/client/public/uploads/${fileName}`, err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }

      res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}` });
    });
  });


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port: ', PORT)
})
```

And this is the code of my page where i want to display the image ( without return markup ):

```
const Orar = () => {

const [file, setFile] = useState("");
const [filename, setFilename] = useState("Choose File");
const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({});

const onChange = (e) => {
  setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
};

const onSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);

  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/upload", formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      }
    });

    const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;

    setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });

    setMessage("File Uploaded");
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.status === 500) {
      setMessage("There was a problem with the server");
    } else {
      setMessage(err.response.data.msg);
    }

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the architecture of your website and database so if you stock only one image inside your website, you can store the id of the uploaded image inside your browser localstorage: [link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (I don't recommend this practice).

A good practice is to store the id or path of your uploaded image inside your database. For example, if you want to edit or display a profile picture, go to your user schema (in your db), stock the id or the path of the uploaded image here. Then when you'll call the @GET /users/:userId, you will retrieve the image id or the image path (depends on which of them you stock).

If you retrieve the link to your image, just do that inside your html code:

```
   <img src={myImageLocation} alt={myImageAlt} />
```

If you stock your image on a dedicated server (it's what you're doing), you can only retrieve the image id and render the image like that:

```
<img src={`${serverPATH}/${imageId}`} alt={myImageAlt} />
```